# How to rename the file on android R and above

Tags: java, android, kotlin, file-rename, mediastore

I have an app in which i want to change the name of audio files in music directory. On Api level < 28 i use to do this.

```
File file = new File(absolutepath);
file.renameTo("new name");

I have tried to look up many resources for the possibility of doing this.
Note: Above provided code works for files generated by my app (On API 30) but if I  unistall the app and install it again then i loose the permission  to rename the file.

Also I dont want to use MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permisssion.
```

Comment: Use SAF to let the user choose the Music directory. You then have full access to all files.

Comment: @blackapps i can read all the files in that folder using READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE even on api 30 i can delete them using MediaStore.createDeleteRequest with permission write external storage now i just have to rename the files

Comment: can you show some code for SAF.

Comment: Use an intent for ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE to let the user pick the directory.

Comment: is there any other way than using SAF, like some mediastore api